# Playwright: How to get each log in separate single line

Tags: typescript, logging, playwright, tslog

Here is the problem statement:

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/18173

Comment: Did you check log4js https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node 
You can append per process (test) in separete file.